# BNF php string that may contain regex (Plugin for intellij idea)

Tags: regex, intellij-idea, bnf

I have such token to define stings

```
string='regexp:(["]([\\]["]|[\\].|[\001-\377])*["])'
```

This token is correct in PHP/GO languages but it doesn't work in my Intelij Plugin after generation custom language definition.

For example folowing string can't be resolved cause contain "\" before "d" `"\d"`

```
"/^[a-f\d]{24}$/i"
```

Question: how i can rewrite regexp to correct  string/regex recognition?

Comment: Best way to get the answer for this question is to ask it at Plugin Development forums: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/200366979-IntelliJ-IDEA-Open-API-and-Plugin-Development

Comment: @VladLuchansky Many thanks going to do it right now